# function wrapping exercise (decorators)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have issue with following exercise:https://pythonprogramming.net/decorators-intermediate-python-tutorial/
Here is code I wanted to write:

```
def add_wrapping(item):
    def wrapped_item():
        return 'a wrapped up box of {}'.format(str(item()))
    return wrapped_item

@add_wrapping
def new_gpu():
    return 'a new Tesla P100 GPU!'
print(new_gpu())
```

Here is my code:

```
def add_wrapping(item):
    def wrapped_item():
        return "a wrapped up box of {}".format(str(item()))
    return wrapped_item()
@add_wrapping
def new_gpu():
    return "new car!"
print(new_gpu())
```

I work in PyCharm, here is error that it gives me:

```
line 17, in <module>
    print(new_gpu())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am stuck at this point, can't figure what went wrong, any help is appreciated!

Comment: use `return wrapped_item`. Currently you're *calling the function before returning*, this results in `new_gpu` being assigned to the result of `wrapped_item()` which is a `str`.

Comment: Why is the code you wanted to write different from the code you wrote?

Comment: Code is different because I didn't want to rewrite his code but created my own, but stil within given exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to return `wrapped_item` object instead of return `wrapped_item()`

for example you can call `func` argument inside your decorator.

```
def add_wrapping(func):
    def wrapped_item():
        return "a wrapped up box of " + func()
    return wrapped_item

@add_wrapping
def new_gpu():
    return "new car!"
print(new_gpu())
```

but it's will work if you returned `str` argument in `new_gpu` function.